# What is the name of this shader pack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mod-identification

I have always seen this shader pack throughout the internet, but I could never find any info about what it was called. (The main differences are the clouds and the water reflections.)

## Screenshot

[image: shaders]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks an awful lot like "[Complementary Shaders - Reimagined](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/shaders/complementary-reimagined)" - notably the *reimagined* style as the page depicts (right side of this image):

[image: shader image]